# Oracle SQL giving different outputs

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Could somebody someone explain why these ORACLE SQL queries giving different output

```
select * from table2
where  not exists(select 1 from table1 a,table2 b where a.name = b.name and a.age = b.age)


select * from table2 b
where not exists(select 1 from table1 a where a.name = b.name and a.age = b.age)
```

Comment: Where is the `FROM` in your sub-queries?

Comment: does it even run fine?

Comment: What makes "Oracle SQL not working" a good title for this question?

Comment: The queries are different, hence outputs

Comment: @T.S. But the a query exactly like one of these, just using `... exists(select 5 ...` instead of `... exists(select 1 ...` would be different from the original as well, but give the same result. ;-)

Comment: @FrankPl I know exactly what these queries are. One is correlated and another is... well... non-related. Anyway. I was reviewing the question, not answering it

Answer (score 4):

The first statement checks locally in the subselect if there are any records where both tables have a common record. If so, it returns **all** records of table2. Otherwise, it returns **no rows**. There is no relationship between the outer table2 and the subselect in the `exists`, you use two unrelated instances of table2.
Hence, this is an all or nothing result: if the `exists` has records, then the outer where condition is true for all rows of the outer table2, otherwise it is false for all rows of the outer table2.

The second query returns the related records of table 2 that have a common record in table1.

Answer (score 2):

`Query#1` Checks for `NOT EXISTS` for data out of join with `Table1` and `Table2`, if so, it fetches **ALL** records of `Table2`, if that join failed with no match, or **NO** record, if atleast one match is found

Whereas `Query#2`, for each row in `Table2`, join with `Table1` and check for if it `NOT EXISTS`. So the result is obvious! Only **Qualified** records come out.